# What are units for this metric?

Tags: integration

Suppose I want to prove that there is a correlation between number of bugs hitting the windshield per second at any given point in time $ b(t) = \frac{dB(t)}{dt} $ and the speed at which a car is going $ d(t) = \frac{d D(t)}{dt}$ where $B(t)$ is a cumulative function of the number of bugs and $D(t)$ is a cumulative function of the number of miles driven.

I am choosing to take an overlap of these two functions $\int{d(t)*b(t) dt}$ and then will normalize by $ \sqrt{\int{d(t)^2 dt} * \int{b^2(t) dt}}$ but don't know what the final units would be for this.

Note that I am also approaching this using PCC, covariance, etc. but am specifically interested in using this overlap methodology here. What would the units of $\int{d(t)*b(t) dt}$ be? After normalization, what would the units be?

Comment: Wait, did you mean to say $d(t)$ or $v(t)$ in your expressions? You have not defined $d(t)$. Let me know and I will edit my answer below accordingly.

Comment: $d(t)$ was what I meant.

Comment: Okay, edited. I did the numerator calculation for you, the denominator should follow in a similar way to prove the end result I claimed by geometric intuition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Letting,
$$\langle f, g \rangle := \int f(t) g(t) dt$$

The expression
$$\frac{\langle f, g \rangle}{\sqrt{\langle f, f \rangle \langle g, g \rangle}}$$

is unitless. It is the infinite dimensional extension of [the cosine of the angle between two vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Geometric_definition), $f$ and $g$.

For your problem, just looking at the numerator, $b(t)d(t)$ has units of
$\frac{\text{bugs}}{\text{second}}\frac{\text{miles}}{\text{second}}$. The integration is over time, so we lose one unit of seconds (think about the definition of the integral, we are *multiplying* by $dt$ which has units of time and then just taking a limit), leaving us with, $$\frac{\text{bugs}\times\text{miles}}{\text{seconds}}$$
The denominator will have the same units after simplification.

By the way, if $f$ and $g$ are considered random variables and the integrals are taken with respect to their joint probability measure, then that expression *is* the PCC (Pearson correlation coefficient) and the numerator *is* their covariance.

Hope that clears things up!